# Paired bluetooth joystick but it won't show at /dev/input or /dev/js

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth, retropie, joystick

I just paired my bluetooth gamepad using https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-setup-bluetooth-on-a-raspberry-pi-3/

Since it's a gamepad (it has a keyboard button but I'm usng in gamepad ode), it should appear at `/dev/input` or `/dev/jsX`, right? There's only `mice` in `/dev/input` and `/dev/jsX` doesn't exist.

Maybe I should bring a kernel module myself?

I'm using raspbian server.

Comment: I don't think it will help, but I'm having the same problem with PiStorms distribution and Raspberry PI 3. Bluetooth pairs OK, no /dev/input entry.